# Setting hypervisorlaunchtype Off causes emulation error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android, emulation

just a bit of background about what I'm trying to accomplish. So I have a personal computer at home running on AMD 3600x (16GB ram). I migrated a virtual machine into my pc so that I can do my mobile development there. But to my dismay upon migrating, I came upon this error "Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)." and I searched around and found this issues forum in GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4587 The fix was running this command into cmd with admin privileges:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

It fixed my problem, however it made me unable to run any of my android emulators' that I created using android studio either inside the VM or from the computer that I'm using itself. So how do I fix this? Or is this unfixable?

Comment: Are you using Hyper-V or VirtualBox?  You've disabled Hyper-V with that command.  The error you posted is a VirtualBox error indicating that the AMD hardware virtualization is not enabled or accessible.  If Hyper-V is enabled, this can cause this, but it can also be caused by Antivirus programs, and other Microsoft features, as well as AMD SVM being disabled.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox for the VM. Right now, I enabled Hyper-V so I can do my development work. I enabled SVM already in the BIOS. The problem is I can't run my virtual machine on virtual box when I have Hyper-V on, but when I turn off Hyper-V I can't run any android emulators either inside the VM or from the computer hosting the VM

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to use both Hyper-V and VirtualBox.

```
"C:\path\to\Virtualbox\VBoxManage" setextradata global "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0
```

This command will allow VirtualBox to use Hyper-V backend or something like that. But it really decrease the VirtualBox performance. I, myself prefer the hyper-v off/auto. For reference read this article https://www.networkreverse.com/2020/06/virtualbox-VERR-NEM-VM-CREATE-FAILED.html